A difficult poker probability question - the dependency of several players sharing a deck
I have been struggling to get my hands around a solution to the following problem: In a regular poker game with a 52-cards deck, what are the odds that someone in a table of N people would have a three of a kind?
The odds for a single person to get three of a kind (excluding full-house) are well known, and can be calculated to be ~2.11% using simple combinatorics/probability theory. However, when including more than one person in the problem, it becomes very hard very fast, almost unreasonably hard. It looks like a pretty simple and natural question to ask, but like many questions in math, I think it is not as simple as it appears, or at least not from the angle I am looking at it. Even in the case of 2 people, the dependency created between the probabilties, due to the deck sharing, makes the problem very challenging, as the tree of possible scenarios grows rapidly.
I would love to hear any creative solutions that untangle this probabilty mess, and purhaps can give a direct formula to the probabilty as a function of the number of people (N).
Note: I want to avoid simple approximations like (1-(1-2.11%)^N), and get an exact formula.

Presumable, then $n\leq10?$ The obvious way is inclusion-exclusion.

I don't think this method will work here from what I've tried.

Can you give details in the question about how you tried it? Seems to work for me.

If it worked for you, can you provide the exact formula?
